# Continuity and convergence everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose a sequence of continuous functions $(h_n)$ converges almost everywhere to another continuous function $h$ .

Is it possible to infer that $h_n$ infact converges everywhere? If not, under what conditions can this possibly be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h_n(x)=x^n$ and $h(x)=0$. Then $h$ and the $h_n$ are continuous, and $h_n(x)\to h(x)$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$, but not everywhere.

Comment: Can you say anything about the  number of discontinuity points in this case? Must it necessarily be countable?

Comment: I don't know a counterexample off the top of my head, but it's not clear to me why it should be countable.